# Qt5/PyQt5 best practices

Tags: qt, oop, pyqt

### Rewritten to clarify as requested.

### Disclaimer:

I am a relative newbie to Qt programming and, to date, I have written only small complexity applications, usually following closely provided examples.

Now I've been asked to (re)write a configuration GUI for an existing product (a cash register, if it matters) based on an embedded Linux which contains a large, possibly expanding, set of "configuration pages". A few examples:

- Software update; allowing to selectively update system and/or application.
- Network setup; allowing Wired and WiFi configuration.
- Internal database update (products, prices, ...)
- Maintenance: view internal logs, memory cleanups, ...
- Export: trigger and configure reports on daily/monthly/yearly activity.
- etc.

I started designing the interface in Qt Designer I quickly realized I was about to get a pretty huge mass of spaghetti-code if I simply tried to make a "bigger version" of what I previously had done.

From this stems the original, very general, question:

*In a complex interface with nested containers (QToolBox, QTabWidget, ...) what is the "approved way" (if any) to partition slots so not to have zillions of them in "MainWindow"?*

*Any pointer to "best practices" for non-trivial examples would be welcome.*

### Status:

I'm currently in design/prototyping stage and I can change things quite easily; later changes might be less handy, of course.

My current design is quite standard:

- a monolithic GUI interface built with Qt Designer with a top-level QToolBox Widget to chose the "page" to edit and individual pages tailored to the specific configuration needs
- import into pyqt5 using the standard paradigm:

```py
    class MWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MWindow, self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi('app.ui', self)

        ...

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- have a backend talking with target and providing "commands" to actually perform required actions (I cannot have a proper MVC because 'M' is elsewhere and 'C' is split, partly on configurator, partly on target).

I quickly discovered I can have tens of slots handled for each single "page" if I want to do proper input validation and be "user friendly" (e.g.: to automatically generate netmask/broadcast from edited IP address, not to speak of the ample code duplication between Ethernet configuration and WiFi Configuration). That is not currently required, but I *know* request will come later on and I want to plan ahead.

### Question:

In other contexts I would have tried to make all UI-related processing more local; e.g.:

- write a class/page to handle IP addresses
- subclass it to add what's required for WiFi.
- build a tabbed widget with a tab for each connection actually available on target, instantiating one of the above classes as needed.
- put the tabbed widget into one of the toolbox pages.
- rinse and repeat.

OTOH some real-life examples (see: [Wireshark's MainWindow](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/ui/qt/main_window.h#L297-L685)) seem to go in the opposite "everything in a single basket" direction.

Is there any, reasonably consolidated, best-practice recommendation to handle this kind of situation?

More to the point: If I insist in splitting code to have a "divide and conquer" approach, how would that translate into QtDesigner/code relationships? (I definitely don't want to resort to hand-code GUI).

Comment: Why would main window have zillions of slots? What does you code in them do?

Comment: @hyde: I edited question, please see if it seems worthy now.

Comment: Kudos for the update, which you obviously put a lot of time into.  However, my guess is the question(s) is too broad and to opinion based. Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the samples provided by Qt will dictate the best practices since most developers would have started with those and would have based their standards on them.

Alternatively, you can use the [KDE practices](https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/development#Best_practices_.26_other_useful_information) as a starting point, since they are probably the biggest Qt project.

But---

Generally, to minimise the complexity of UI elements (e.g. Main Window) and make applications more decoupled (thus, more maintainable), you can use the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern.

In a typical use-case, each UI element (the 'view') is backed by a controller class and a model class. When a signal is triggered, the appropriate method on the controller is called. The controller method, in turn, calls a method on the model and/or changes another UI element.

The above example presents a one-to-one association between view, controller, and model, but you can vary this according to your requirements.

There are other modern derivatives of MVC (e.g. MVVM and MVP), but I prefer it because of its simplicity and also because the other patterns are more effective when the framework in use supports them.